# Raster and shapefiles are not overlapping in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I plotted a raster map using matplotlib. When I overlay a shapefile, the raster seems to be shifted a bit.

[image]

The same raster and shapefile overlap each other perfectly in ArcGIS.

Here is what I am trying,

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from osgeo import gdal
from numpy import linspace
from numpy import meshgrid
import numpy as np

ds = gdal.Open('Path\\\To\\Raster.tif')
data = ds.ReadAsArray()

gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
proj = ds.GetProjection()

xres = gt[1]
yres = gt[5]

xmin = gt[0] + xres * 0.5
xmax = gt[0] + (xres * ds.RasterXSize) - xres * 0.5
ymin = gt[3] + (yres * ds.RasterYSize) + yres * 0.5
ymax = gt[3] - yres * 0.5

x_center=(xmin+xmax)/2
y_center=(ymin+ymax)/2

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, axisbg='w', frame_on=True)

m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=xmin,llcrnrlat=ymin,urcrnrlon=xmax,urcrnrlat=ymax,
             projection='merc', lat_0 = y_center, lon_0 = x_center)
m.readshapefile('Path\\To\\Shapefile.shp','units', color='#444444', linewidth=0.5)

parallels = np.arange(15.,30.,0.25)
m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[1,0,0,0],fontsize=12, linewidth=0.4)  

meridians = np.arange(70.,90.,0.25)
m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[0,0,0,1],fontsize=12, linewidth=0.4)

x = linspace(0, m.urcrnrx, data.shape[1])
y = linspace(0, m.urcrnry, data.shape[0])

xx, yy = meshgrid(x, y)
p=m.pcolormesh(xx, yy, data)

plt.show()
```

How to adjust this shift?